# java.sql.SQLException: Parameter number 2 is not an OUT parameter

Tags: java, sql

I am getting an Error while running this:

```
1. cs = getCon1().prepareCall("{CALL SaveLabourWageDetails(?,?)}");

2. cs.setString(1, user.getUserId());

3. cs.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.INTEGER); //<--- ERROR at this line

4. cs.execute();

5. String lastIsertId=cs.getString(2);
```

The  Stored Procedure is :

```
CREATE

    PROCEDURE `cheque_alert`.`SaveLabourDetailsHead`(IN wage_entered_by VARCHAR(10),OUT LastInsertId INT)

    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `cheque_alert`.`labour_wage_head`
            (
             `wage_entered_by`,
             `entered_date_time`)
    VALUES (wage_entered_by,
         NOW());

          SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO LastInsertId;

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Please point out the problem in this code..

Comment: The procedure is named `SaveLabourDetailsHead` and you call `SaveLabourWageDetails`, that might be the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `{? = CALL SaveLabourDetailsHead(?)}`

Comment: I made a simple mistake.. and spoiled lot of time.. thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling wrong procedure. You have procedure `SaveLabourDetailsHead` and you are calling

```
1. cs = getCon1().prepareCall("{CALL SaveLabourWageDetails(?,?)}");  
                                         ↑
```

Change to,

```
1. cs = getCon1().prepareCall("{CALL SaveLabourDetailsHead(?)}");
```

Set String parameter `wage_entered_by`.

Answer (score 0):

Your out parameter is of type String, but it should be int. Try this out.

```
int lastIsertId=cs.getInt(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but the output exception is misleading as the root cause was the procedure name.

I typed incorrect procedure which did not exist in database.

Instead of providing a SQL exception something like "routine does not exist", it gave:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter number 2 is not an OUT parameter.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem.

It was a permission issue in my case. The MySQL user my application uses lacked the `EXECUTE` permission on the schema I'm working on.

```sql
GRANT EXECUTE ON <your_schema>.* TO '<your_user>'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was chasing this for ages, then found out I'd missed and underscore from the name of the stored procedure! I didn't even have a procedure with the incorrect name.

What a stupid error message!

"The parameter is wrong - ooh, by the way, that procedure doesn't exist"