# Oracle SOA BPEL calling a MySQL Procedure - parameter number 2 is not an out parameter

Tags: mysql, oracle, soa, procedure, bpel

Currently I have a use case where I need to invoke a Mysql Procedure thorough Oracle BPEL. The adapter configuration is fine and shows me the available In/Out parameters during the configuration and the composite is deployed successfully. However the invocation is failed during the webs service call.
Any idea about the issue particularly in SOA. The weblogic version is 12c & I am using jDev 11g for the composite development.
 Below is the error message received during the web service call-

```
The selected operation process could not be invoked.
A fault occurred while invoking the webservice operation. The fault is : <env:Fault xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<faultcode>env:Server</faultcode>
<faultstring>Exception occurred when binding was invoked.
Exception occurred during invocation of JCA binding: "JCA Binding execute of Reference operation 'getUserFirstName' failed due to: Register out parameter error.
Error registering parameter First_Name as an out parameter.
An error occurred when registering parameter First_Name as an out parameter of the getUserName API. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter number 2 is not an OUT parameter
Check to ensure that the parameter is a valid IN/OUT or OUT parameter of the API. This exception is considered retriable, likely due to a communication failure. To classify it as non-retriable instead add property nonRetriableErrorCodes with value "0" to your deployment descriptor (i.e. weblogic-ra.xml). To auto retry a retriable fault set these composite.xml properties for this invoke: jca.retry.interval, jca.retry.count, and jca.retry.backoff. All properties are integers.
". 
The invoked JCA adapter raised a resource exception.
Please examine the above error message carefully to determine a resolution.
</faultstring>
<faultactor/>
<detail>
<exception>Parameter number 2 is not an OUT parameter</exception>
</detail>
</env:Fault>
oracle.sysman.emInternalSDK.webservices.util.SoapTestException: Client received SOAP Fault from server : Exception occurred when binding was invoked.
Exception occurred during invocation of JCA binding: "JCA Binding execute of Reference operation 'getUserFirstName' failed due to: Register out parameter error.
Error registering parameter First_Name as an out parameter.
An error occurred when registering parameter First_Name as an out parameter of the getUserName API. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter number 2 is not an OUT parameter
Check to ensure that the parameter is a valid IN/OUT or OUT parameter of the API. This exception is considered retriable, likely due to a communication failure. To classify it as non-retriable instead add property nonRetriableErrorCodes with value "0" to your deployment descriptor (i.e. weblogic-ra.xml). To auto retry a retriable fault set these composite.xml properties for this invoke: jca.retry.interval, jca.retry.count, and jca.retry.backoff. All properties are integers.
". 
The invoked JCA adapter raised a resource exception.
Please examine the above error message carefully to determine a resolution.
```

**Step wise DB Adapter configuration is here-**

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cei0OFje1dmefDn7PfBIjxW4vb81Ngez

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a mistake while you are selecting in and out parameters, probably you have added more variable than your database are expecting. Please look at the following and if possible send more details like screenshots of your db adapter configurations and db table

[java.sql.SQLException: Parameter number 2 is not an OUT parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581950/java-sql-sqlexception-parameter-number-2-is-not-an-out-parameter)

Comment: DBAdapter configuration wizard added!

Comment: Yes, you add it but I mean that while you are selecting input and output variables in your adapter, you may have selected more than db expecting. Please check you db adapter again.